# .Net Core -Prepopulating foreign(parent) key in child record from parent results in error in navigation after ‘create child record’ save

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hi I have a parent child relationship between two entities- PositionSummary and PositionDetail.

Here are the models.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Models
{
    public partial class Possummary
    {
        public Possummary()
        {
            Posdetail = new HashSet<Posdetail>();
        }

        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public string PositionNbr { get; set; }
        public string WorkTitle { get; set; }
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
        public double? JobValue { get; set; }
        public double? TimeTotal { get; set; }
        public double? Fte { get; set; }
        public double? Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Lastupdated { get; set; }
        public string JobFamily { get; set; }
        public int? DescriptionTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Descriptiontype DescriptionType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Posdetail> Posdetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Models
{
    public partial class Posdetail
    {
        public int PosdetailId { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
        public int Workitem { get; set; }
        public int? TimeSpent { get; set; }
        public int? ImportanceId { get; set; }
        public double? TimeNrmz { get; set; }
        public int? Knowdepth { get; set; }
        public int? Need { get; set; }
        public int? TimeCalc { get; set; }
        public double? Postskval { get; set; }
        public double? Ftetime { get; set; }
        public double? Ftesal { get; set; }
        public DateTime Lastupdated { get; set; }

        public virtual Imp Importance { get; set; }
        public virtual Knowdep KnowdepthNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Possummary Position { get; set; }
        public virtual Timescale TimeSpentNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Workhier WorkitemNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Parent successfully navigates to the selected child records list. On the child list page I am navigating to a child create page with a parameter ( the parent foreign key) because I don’t want to enter  the parent foreign key each time.
The create page OnPostAsync procedure returns to the child list page after the save (ie standard scaffolding code).
My code compiles without error. When I hit the create button the create page the record DOES save it in the SQL server database BUT the navigation back to the child list page results in an error.

The error is:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail.Pages_PositionDetail_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
14.         Create New

The idea would be that upon return to child list- that the return would be successful and that if another create was asked for- the parent foreign key default would still be in effect.

**Questions:

1. Why am I getting the above error?
2. How do I have the parent foreign key remain in effect between the list and the create pages upon repeated ‘create’ entries?
3. Same question as 2- but returning repeatedly to create page with ‘back to list’ as way of navigating out?**

In general I am finding that creating of child records on a different razor page (standard scaffolding using entity framework) leaves a lot to be desired- quite cumbersome when the need to create child records  prepopulating the parent foreign key would be a common scenario.

Thoughts?

Below are the cshtml files and cs files for the PositionSummary and PositionDetail

PositionSummary

```
@page
@model ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionSummary.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Position Summary</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="Possum-data-table"
                       class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                       style="width:100%">
                    @*<table class="table">*@
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].PositionNbr)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].WorkTitle)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].Purpose)
                            </th>
                            
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Possummary)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionNbr)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkTitle)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purpose)
                            </td>
                           
                        <td>
                            <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Edit</a> |
                            @*<a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Details</a> |*@
                            <a asp-page="../PositionDetail/Index" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Position Details</a> |

                            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts
    {
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#Possum-data-table').DataTable({ "order": [[0, "asc"]] });

        });
    </script>
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ThePositionerRazor2.Models;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionSummary
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context _context;

        public IndexModel(ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Possummary> Possummary { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Possummary = await _context.Possummary
                .Include(p => p.DescriptionType).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Position Details Index

```
@page
@model ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>



<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
        <a asp-page="/PositionDetail/Create" asp-route-PositionID="@Model.Posdetail[0].PositionId">Create New</a>

</p>


<form method="post">
    <p>
        Desired Position: @Html.TextBox("SelectedPosition")
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Positions" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                    <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Position Detail</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="posdet-data-table"
                           class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                           style="width:100%">
                        @*<table class="table">*@
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Position)
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].WorkitemNavigation)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].TimeNrmz)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Importance)
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Posdetail[0].Lastupdated)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.Posdetail)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position.PositionNbr)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkitemNavigation.Workitemid)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeNrmz)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Importance.ImportanceId)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastupdated)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Edit</a> |
                                        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Details</a> |
                                        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PosdetailId">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    @section Scripts
        {
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#posdet-data-table').DataTable({ "order": [[0, "desc"]] });

            });
        </script>



    }



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ThePositionerRazor2.Models;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context _context;

        public IndexModel(ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public IList<Posdetail> Posdetail { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(int? ID, string SelectedPosition)

        {


            if (ID != null)
            {
                Posdetail = await _context.Posdetail
                .Include(p => p.Importance)
                .Include(p => p.KnowdepthNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.Position)
                .Include(p => p.TimeSpentNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.WorkitemNavigation)
        .Where(p => p.Position.PositionId == ID)
         .ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Posdetail = await _context.Posdetail
                    .Include(p => p.Importance)
                    .Include(p => p.KnowdepthNavigation)
                    .Include(p => p.Position)
                    .Include(p => p.TimeSpentNavigation)
                    .Include(p => p.WorkitemNavigation)
                    .Where(p => p.Position.PositionNbr == SelectedPosition)
                    .ToListAsync();
            }
        }
        public async Task OnPostAsync(string SelectedPosition)
        {
            Posdetail = await _context.Posdetail
                .Include(p => p.Importance)
                .Include(p => p.KnowdepthNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.Position)
                .Include(p => p.TimeSpentNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.WorkitemNavigation)
                .Where(p => p.Position.PositionNbr == SelectedPosition)
                .ToListAsync();

        }


    }
}
```

Position Details Create

```
@page
@model ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PosDetailList.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Posdetail</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.PositionId" class="form-control"
                        
                        asp-items="ViewBag.PositionId">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Workitem" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Workitem"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.TimeSpent" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TimeSpent"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.ImportanceId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ImportanceId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeNrmz" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Posdetail.Knowdepth" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Knowdepth"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Need" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Need" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.TimeCalc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Postskval" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftetime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Ftesal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Posdetail.Lastupdated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using ThePositionerRazor2.Models;

namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PosDetailList
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context _context;

        public CreateModel(ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet(int PositionID)
        {
            int ID = 5;
        ViewData["ImportanceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Imp, "ImportanceId", "ImportanceId");
        ViewData["Knowdepth"] = new SelectList(_context.Knowdep, "DepthId", "DepthId");
        ViewData["PositionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Possummary, "PositionId", "PositionNbr", PositionID);
          

            ViewData["TimeSpent"] = new SelectList(_context.Timescale, "TimevalId", "TimevalId");
        ViewData["Workitem"] = new SelectList(_context.Workhier, "Workitemid", "Workitemid");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Posdetail Posdetail { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            
            _context.Posdetail.Add(Posdetail);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the navigation back to the child list page results in an error

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

To fix the error, you can try to pass selected `PositionId` through route value to Index page by modifying code like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Posdetail.Add(Posdetail);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var positionId = Posdetail.PositionId;

    return RedirectToPage("./Index", new { ID = positionId });
}
```